Using BitBlt to capture a screenshot
I've been trying to create a .bmp file using functions like BitBlt, CreateCompatibleDC... in the kernel.
The problem is whenever I run this code it creates a .bmp file successfully, the only issue is that the file is 1 kB of size. Even thought it's supposed to be way more
Here is my code:
#include "Drawing.h"

NTSTATUS NTAPI
__NE_CreateFile(
    _In_ LPCWSTR                FilePath,
    _Inout_ PHANDLE             FileHandle
);

NTSTATUS NTAPI
__NE_WriteFile(
    _In_ HANDLE                 FileHandle,
    _In_ PVOID                  Buffer,
    _In_ ULONG                  BufferSize
);

NTSTATUS NTAPI
__NE_CloseFile(
    _In_ HANDLE                 FileHandle
);

BOOLEAN NTAPI
__NE_CaptureScreenshot(
    VOID
);

NTSTATUS NTAPI
DriverEntry(
    _In_ PDRIVER_OBJECT         DriverObject,
    _In_ PUNICODE_STRING        RegistryPath
) {
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(DriverObject);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(RegistryPath);

    // Ignore this, it's supposed to retrieve GDI routines
    BOOLEAN Stats = InitializeSequence();
    if (Stats == FALSE) {
        KdPrintEx((DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_ERROR_LEVEL, "Failed to initialize sequence.\xA"));
    }

    __NE_CaptureScreenshot();

    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}

NTSTATUS NTAPI
__NE_CreateFile(
    _In_ LPCWSTR                FilePath,
    _Inout_ PHANDLE             FileHandle
) {
    NTSTATUS Status;
    OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES ObjectAttributes;
    KEVENT Event;
    IO_STATUS_BLOCK IoStatusBlock;
    UNICODE_STRING FileName;

    RtlInitUnicodeString(&FileName, FilePath);

    KeInitializeEvent(&Event, NotificationEvent, FALSE);

    InitializeObjectAttributes(
        &ObjectAttributes,
        &FileName,
        OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE | OBJ_KERNEL_HANDLE,
        NULL,
        NULL
    );

    Status = ZwCreateFile(
        FileHandle,
        GENERIC_WRITE,
        &ObjectAttributes,
        &IoStatusBlock,
        NULL,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
        0,
        FILE_CREATE,
        FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT,
        NULL,
        0
    );

    if (NT_SUCCESS(Status) == FALSE) {
        KdPrintEx((DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_ERROR_LEVEL, "[IN] Failed to create file. Status: 0x%08X, IoStatus: 0x%08X\xA", Status, IoStatusBlock.Status));
        return Status;
    }

    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}


NTSTATUS NTAPI
__NE_WriteFile(
    _In_ HANDLE                 FileHandle,
    _In_ PVOID                  Buffer,
    _In_ ULONG                  BufferSize
) {
    NTSTATUS                    Status;
    IO_STATUS_BLOCK             IoStatusBlock;

    Status = ZwWriteFile(
        FileHandle,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        &IoStatusBlock,
        Buffer,
        BufferSize,
        NULL,
        NULL
    );

    if (NT_SUCCESS(Status) == FALSE) {
        KdPrintEx((DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_ERROR_LEVEL, "Failed to write to file.\xA"));
        return Status;
    }

    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}

NTSTATUS NTAPI
__NE_CloseFile(
    _In_ HANDLE                 FileHandle
) {
    NTSTATUS                    Status;

    Status = ZwClose(FileHandle);

    if (NT_SUCCESS(Status) == FALSE) {
        KdPrintEx((DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_ERROR_LEVEL, "Failed to close file.\xA"));
        return Status;
    }

    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}

BOOLEAN NTAPI
__NE_CaptureScreenshot(
    VOID
) {
    BITMAP Bitmap = { 0 };
    HANDLE FileHandle = { 0 };

    HDC ScreenDC = NtUserGetDC(NULL);

    if (ScreenDC == NULL) {
        KdPrintEx((DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_ERROR_LEVEL, "Failed to get screen DC.\xA"));
        return FALSE;
    }

    HDC CompatibleDC = GreCreateCompatibleDC(ScreenDC);

    if (CompatibleDC == NULL) {
        KdPrintEx((DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_ERROR_LEVEL, "Failed to create compatible DC.\xA"));
        return FALSE;
    }

    INT ScreenWidth = GreGetDeviceCaps(ScreenDC, HORZRES);
    INT ScreenHeight = GreGetDeviceCaps(ScreenDC, VERTRES);

    HBITMAP CompatibleBitmap = NtGdiCreateCompatibleBitmap(
        ScreenDC,
        ScreenWidth,
        ScreenHeight
    );

    if (CompatibleBitmap == NULL) {
        KdPrintEx((DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_ERROR_LEVEL, "Failed to create compatible bitmap.\xA"));
        return FALSE;
    }

    NtGdiSelectBitmap(CompatibleDC, CompatibleBitmap);

    BOOLEAN BitBlitStatus = NtGdiBitBlt(
        CompatibleDC,
        0,
        0,
        ScreenWidth,
        ScreenHeight,
        ScreenDC,
        0,
        0,
        SRCCOPY
    );

    if (BitBlitStatus == FALSE) {
        KdPrintEx((DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_ERROR_LEVEL, "Failed to bitblt.\xA"));
        return FALSE;
    }

    NtGdiExtGetObjectW(CompatibleBitmap, sizeof(BITMAP), &Bitmap);

    BITMAPFILEHEADER BitmapFileHeader = { 0 };
    BITMAPINFOHEADER BitmapInfoHeader = { 0 };

    BitmapInfoHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    BitmapInfoHeader.biWidth = Bitmap.bmWidth;
    BitmapInfoHeader.biHeight = Bitmap.bmHeight;
    BitmapInfoHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    BitmapInfoHeader.biBitCount = 32;
    BitmapInfoHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    BitmapInfoHeader.biSizeImage = Bitmap.bmWidthBytes * Bitmap.bmHeight;
    BitmapInfoHeader.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
    BitmapInfoHeader.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
    BitmapInfoHeader.biClrUsed = 0;
    BitmapInfoHeader.biClrImportant = 0;

    DWORD BitmapSize = BitmapInfoHeader.biSizeImage;

    HANDLE DIBHandle = ExAllocatePool2(
        POOL_FLAG_NON_PAGED,
        BitmapSize,
        'dib0'
    );

    if (DIBHandle == NULL) {
        KdPrintEx((DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_ERROR_LEVEL, "Failed to allocate DIB handle.\xA"));
        return FALSE;
    }

    NtGdiGetDIBitsInternal(
        ScreenDC,
        CompatibleBitmap,
        0,
        (UINT)Bitmap.bmHeight,
        DIBHandle,
        (PBITMAPINFO)&BitmapInfoHeader,
        DIB_RGB_COLORS,
        0
    );

    __NE_CreateFile(
        L"\\??\\C:\\Screenshot.bmp",
        &FileHandle
    );

    DWORD DIBSize = BitmapSize + sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);

    BitmapFileHeader.bfOffBits = (DWORD)sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + (DWORD)sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    BitmapFileHeader.bfSize = DIBSize;
    BitmapFileHeader.bfType = 0x4D42;

    PVOID buffer = ExAllocatePool2(
        POOL_FLAG_NON_PAGED,
        DIBSize,
        'buf0'
    );

    if (buffer == NULL) {
        KdPrintEx((DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_ERROR_LEVEL, "Failed to allocate buffer.\xA"));
        ExFreePool(DIBHandle);
        return FALSE;
    }

    RtlCopyMemory(buffer, &BitmapFileHeader, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER));
    RtlCopyMemory((PBYTE)buffer + sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), &BitmapInfoHeader, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER));
    RtlCopyMemory((PBYTE)buffer + sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), DIBHandle, BitmapSize);

    __NE_WriteFile(
        FileHandle,
        (LPSTR)buffer,
        DIBSize
    );

    ExFreePool(buffer);
    ExFreePool(DIBHandle);

    __NE_CloseFile(FileHandle);

    return TRUE;
}

I've tried to change the Size calculations etc.. but none of it worked. I followed this PoC
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/capturing-an-image
EDIT:
BOOLEAN NTAPI
__NE_CaptureScreenshot(
    VOID
) {
    HDC hScreenDC = NtUserGetDC(NULL);
    if (!hScreenDC) return FALSE;

    int width = GreGetDeviceCaps(hScreenDC, HORZRES);
    int height = GreGetDeviceCaps(hScreenDC, VERTRES);

    HDC hMemDC = GreCreateCompatibleDC(hScreenDC);
    HBITMAP hBitmap = NtGdiCreateCompatibleBitmap(hScreenDC, width, height);
    NtGdiSelectBitmap(hMemDC, hBitmap);

    NtGdiBitBlt(hMemDC, 0, 0, width, height, hScreenDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

    BITMAPINFO bmi = { 0 };
    bmi.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    bmi.bmiHeader.biWidth = width;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biHeight = -height;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;

    PVOID pBits = ExAllocatePool2(POOL_FLAG_NON_PAGED, width * height * 4, 'BMP0');
    if (!pBits) return FALSE;

    NtGdiGetDIBitsInternal(hMemDC, hBitmap, 0, height, pBits, &bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS, 0);

    HANDLE hFile;
    UNICODE_STRING fileName;
    OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES objAttr;
    IO_STATUS_BLOCK ioStatusBlock;
    RtlInitUnicodeString(&fileName, L"\\??\\C:\\screen.bmp");
    InitializeObjectAttributes(&objAttr, &fileName, OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE | OBJ_KERNEL_HANDLE, NULL, NULL);

    NTSTATUS status = ZwCreateFile(&hFile, GENERIC_WRITE, &objAttr, &ioStatusBlock, NULL, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0, FILE_OVERWRITE_IF, FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT, NULL, 0);
    if (NT_SUCCESS(status) == FALSE)
        return FALSE;

    BITMAPFILEHEADER bmfHeader = { 0 };
    bmfHeader.bfType = 0x4D42;
    bmfHeader.bfOffBits = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    bmfHeader.bfSize = bmfHeader.bfOffBits + (width * height * 4);

    ZwWriteFile(hFile, NULL, NULL, NULL, &ioStatusBlock, &bmfHeader, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), NULL, NULL);
    ZwWriteFile(hFile, NULL, NULL, NULL, &ioStatusBlock, &bmi.bmiHeader, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), NULL, NULL);
    ZwWriteFile(hFile, NULL, NULL, NULL, &ioStatusBlock, pBits, width * height * 4, NULL, NULL);

    ZwClose(hFile);

    return TRUE;
}

This code creates a correct .bmp but it's blank black

Before invoking NtGdiExtGetObjectW(CompatibleBitmap, sizeof(BITMAP), &Bitmap); the bmBits member of Bitmap should probably be initialized to point to enough memory to hold the bits.

It is quite difficult to figure out what is wrong, because there seems to be no documentation anywhere on the interwebz for things like NtGdiExtGetObjectW or NtGdiExtGetObject.

These functions are just GetObject @MikeNakis
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getobject

If the image is correct but the file apparently isn't big enough, does it have run length compression? Although the BI_RGB value means no compression.

No compression.

NtGdiGetDIBitsInternal() is failing, and you're not checking return codes everywhere. It's failing because it expects the buffers for the bit data and BITMAPHEADERINFO to reside in user mode. You can alleviate this by allocating them in user mode via ZwAllocateVirtualMemory(). However, I get all-white BMP files so there's something else still amiss.

Doh, it was a typo when copying over the code. With the different memory allocation now it works for me.

@Luke what do you mean? and which code will work with ZwAllocateVirtualMemory()

@Luke I've did as you told me to do, I still get blank black image ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Haha man, found the issue. Managed to get it working thanks alot @Luke
